# Getting "ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_ALREADYOPEN" while syncing data to DropBox in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on Ipad application.I integrated Dropbox to my app.It consists of two view controllers.In its syncing fine in ViewController1,while I am trying to sync data I am getting the "ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_ALREADYOPEN: database_manager.cpp:155: datastore default already open".

I have taken DBDatastore reference in Appdelegate and using the sane reference in both viewcontrollers

In AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) DBDatastore *store;
```

In ViewController1

```
{
  if (self.account)
{

    customerTbl = [self.store getTable:@"CustomerDetails"];

    DBRecord *task = [customerTbl insert:@{ @"CustomerName": nametextfield.text,    @"VehicleLicence": drivinglicencetextfield.text,]} ];



    NSLog(@"cust appDelegate.store.datastoreId is %@",appDelegate.store.datastoreId);

    if (appDelegate.store.status & (DBDatastoreIncoming | DBDatastoreOutgoing))
    {
        [appDelegate syncTasks];
    }


    [appDelegate.store sync:nil];



} else
{
    store = nil;
    // tasks = nil;
}

}
```

In ViewController2

```
{
if (self.account)
    {

        DBTable *customerTbl = [self.store getTable:@"PriceList"];

      DBRecord *task = [customerTbl insert:@{ @"Code": admincodeTextField.text, @"Tier1": admintier1TextField.text,@"Tier2": admintier2TextField.text,@"Tier3": admintier3TextField.text,@"CRV": admincvrTextField.text]} ];



        if (appDelegate.store.status & (DBDatastoreIncoming | DBDatastoreOutgoing))
        {
            [appDelegate syncTasks];
        }

        [appDelegate.store sync:nil];



    } else
    {
        store = nil;
    }
}
```

I had gone through this sample  [link](http://github.com/Swaroop1231/DropBox-Sample)

I am unable to get where it has gone wrong.Could any body help who worked on this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you're opening the datastore more than once, but this part of the code doesn't seem to do that. Can you share the part of the code that actually opens the datastore? Maybe add some logging around it so you can see if it's being called more than once? Also, does this error occur when the app first loads, or when you take some action? (If so, what?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @smarx.Its happening every time while saving the data from Viewcontroller1 to Viewcontroller2 and trying to sync data there,and also happening same viceversa.

Comment: Well, you responded to one of my questions. How about the others? :-)

Comment: As far as I can tell, that repo just has an empty README in it. :-)

Comment: Hi @smarx.I solved the above problem.I made a small mistake in my code.Right now I am havig a doubt.My doubt is "I enabled additional users to my app.I had used app key and secret of one account,say Acount1@gmail.com and in my app I login with other (say Account2@gmail.com) account.When I synced data where the data stores are save? The data was not saved in both the accounts.Where can I see those data stores? "